# Display Custom Post Type w/ Taxonomy/Category Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I am working on creating a shortcode function that will display a custom post type and is filterable by its category/taxonomy. I've figured out how to create the shortcode and have it display the post type. But I cannot get it to display the associated taxonomy categories.

I have created a custom post type called 'testimonials' I then created a taxonomy called 'testimonial-category'. Inside of this taxonomy I have a category called 'testimonial-home'.

I want to be able to use the shortcode with the 'testimonial-home' as its filter in order to display home page testimonials.

My shortcode works great without attributes: [list-testimonials] - this displays all testimonials. But when I add: [list-testimonials category="testimonial-home"] nothing is displayed.

I'm stumped. I'm so close and I'm sure there is something very obvious that I am overlooking. Any and all help is so greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here's my shortcode function:

// create shortcode with parameters so that the user can define what's queried - default is to list all blog posts

```
    add_shortcode( 'list-testimonials', 'post_listing_parameters_shortcode' );
    function post_listing_parameters_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();

    // define attributes and their defaults
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'type' => 'testimonials',
        'order' => 'date',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts' => -1,
        'category' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    // define query parameters based on attributes
    $options = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'category_name' => $category,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $options );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div
        class="small-12 medium-12 large-4 columns testimonial-column homepage-    testimonial-column">

        <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL CONTAINER-->
        <div
            class="testimonial-container homepage-testimonial-container"  
            id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL TEXT-->
            <?php if( get_field('testimonial_text') ): ?>
            <div
                 class="testimonial testimonial-textarea">
                    <?php the_field('testimonial_text'); ?>   
            </div>
            <?php endif ?>
            <!--END HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL TEXT-->

            <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL DETAILS-->
            <div
                 class="testimonial-details">

                <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL IMAGE-->
                <?php if( get_field('testimonial_photo') ): ?>
                <img
                     src="<?php the_field('testimonial_photo'); ?>"
                     class="testimonial-photo" />
                <?php endif ?>

                <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL BIO INFO-->
                <div
                    class="testimonial-bio">

                    <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL NAME-->
                    <?php if( get_field('testimonial_name') ): ?>
                    <h5
                        class="testimonial-name">
                            <?php the_field('testimonial_name'); ?> 
                    </h5>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <!--END HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL NAME-->

                    <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL TITLE-->
                    <?php if( get_field('testimonial_title') ): ?>
                    <p
                       class="testimonial-title">
                           <?php the_field('testimonial_title'); ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <!--END HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL TITLE-->

                    <!--HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL COMPANY-->
                    <?php if( get_field('testimonial_company') ): ?>
                    <p
                       class="testimonial-company">
                           <?php the_field('testimonial_company'); ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <!--END HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL COMPANY-->

                </div>
                <!--END HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL BIO INFO-->

            </div>
            <!--END HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL DETAILS-->

    </div>
    <!--END HOME PAGE SINGLE TESTIMONIAL CONTAINER-->
    </div>
    <!--HOME PAGE TESTIMONIALS COLUMN-->

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
return $myvariable; 
   }    
}
```

Comment: Never ever use `extract()`. It really problematic and extremely hard to debug as it creates variables left right and centre on the fly. For these reasons, it was removed from core and the codex. Please do not ever use `extract()`. Just to add, are you sure you are using build in categories or a custom taxonomy?

Comment: I'm using a custom taxonomy? So is that the issue? Am I calling it wrong? How would I call a custom taxonomy?

So would my shortcode look like [list-testimonials taxonomy="home-testimonials"]...? I've tried this but to no avail. But that isn't included in my shortcode function. So would I do the following instead...

Comment: // define attributes and their defaults
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'type' => 'testimonials',
        'order' => 'date',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts' => -1,
        'taxonomy' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    // define query parameters based on attributes
    $options = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'taxonomy_name' => $category,
    );

Answer (score 4):

I would start (if you haven't already) with making sure the query works "in vivo", that is, by itself on a page (not as a shortcode). Then iterate from there. Since custom taxonomies use a whole slew of different functions and key names than categories do, it's important to test this first. Also, to be super overly pedantic: when referring to a custom taxonomy, the term for *categories* is **term** or terms.

For what it's worth, a pristine custom post type loop example:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'testimonials', // This is the CPT's slug!
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'testimonial-category', // This is the taxonomy's slug!
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('testimonial-home') // This is the term's slug!
        )
    ),
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order'
  );
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($my_query->have_posts()): 
  while($my_query->have_posts()): $my_query->the_post(); ?>
      <li>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php if($thumbnail): ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[url]; ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
      </li>
  <?php endwhile; // End while $my_query->have_posts
endif; // End if $my_query->have_posts

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I would also think that the OP is using a custom taxonomy and not the build in taxonomy `category`. ;-)